# why does python submodule not show up in list from dir(module)?

Tags: python, python-import

This is probably a more general question, because I have seen similar behavior with other modules.  But I will show the issue as I am seeing it with module `matplotlib`.  I thought that `dir(module)` lists all attributes of the specified module.  So I can do the following:

```
import matplotlib
dir(matplotlib)
```

Among the results listed is 'dateutil', but 'dates' is NOT listed by `dir(matplotlib)`.  But then I do this:

```
import matplotlib.dates   ## why does this work? `dir(matplotlib)` did not list it
dir(matplotlib)           ## this now lists both 'dates' and 'dateutil'
```

Why does `dir(matplotlib)` now list 'dates' as one of its attributes?

What's going on here?

I just noticed now, it appears to me that dateutil is not actually part of matplotlib, but is imported by matplotlib:

```
In [11]: matplotlib.dateutil.__file__
Out[11]: '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/__init__.py'

In [12]: matplotlib.__file__
Out[12]: '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py'

In [13]: matplotlib.dates.__file__
Out[13]: '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py'
```

Notice in the output above, `matplotlib.dateutil.__file__` shows a file that is not even in the matplotlib directory.  Furthermore I can see in file `'/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py'` that dateutil is imported by `matplotlib/__init__.py`.

So when I run `dir(module)` is there an easy way to tell which attributes are part of the module itself, and which were imported by the module?  And how could I have know (other than reading documentation, or "ls"ing the matplotlib directory) that 'dates' is also a valid "attribute" and "module" within matplotlib?

Comment: `matplotlib` (the package) doesn't include/declare `dates` (a module in its package) in matplotlib's `__init__.py`, but imported `dateutil` from standard library in there. so you have to import it manually.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting that as I'm looking this over, but the questions are:
1. Why is it set up that way (that the submodule `dates` is not declared in the main module)?  what are the pros and cons of doing that?
2. Is there a way to list the submodules that are not directly imported or declared?
3. Is there an easy way (other than looking at `matplotlib.dateutil.__file__`) that I could have known that the dateutil submodule was imported by matplotlib, and not actually directly part of it?

Comment: Look at `matplotlib.dateutil.__module__` rather than `matplotlib.dateutil.__file__`

Comment: first of all, it's not attribute. 1: did you read that `__init__.py`? quite obvious to me, because matplotlib is also a cli tool. 2 & 3: there's no easy way other than reading the doc or browsing the package, unless you changed the source code to suit your preference. you're given the access to that code by their devs, so their source code dictates the majority of methods for usage. running `dir` isn't actually an official way to discovering modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `matplotlib` does not itself `import .dates`. What `dir()` shows you is a list of attributes of an object. If `matplotlib` does not `import .dates`, then there's no local name `dates` on the `matplotlib` module object.

Now, if you do `import matplotlib.dates`, Python's import system resolves that to the file/folder `matplotlib/dates.py` or `matplotlib/dates/__init__.py`, whichever exists. It's important to emphasise that `matplotlib` itself has nothing to do with that file resolution and hence does not need to "know" in any way about the existence of that submodule.

If you load a module, it does *not* automatically load all possible submodules as well. That only happens if something explicitly `import`s that name.

Comment: Right, got confused there for a second. Corrected.